# .NET Pages Hang in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008

We have a very odd but major issue with an internal web application. It is written in asp.net 4.0 and has been working fine for a while. However a few days ago it suddenly stopped working in IE10,9 and 8. On certain pages when clicking a button the page hangs for up to an hour. This does not happen in Opera, Chrome or Firefox, but it does happen in all current versions of IE. Some of the PCs have not been rebooted for months so we do not think it is due to an update to IE. Also if we deploy the application to a different server everything works fine for IE too..... It also does not happen when running the site from a development environment. So we have discovered that it only happens when the site is running on either the live server or the test server (both almost identical but not quite) and even then it only happens when accessing the site from IE!

The live and test servers are both win 2008 while the server that it does work on is win 2003 and my dev environment is on windows 7.

Anyone have any ideas about what might be going on or where we could start looking?

EDIT--------------------------------------------------

We have discovered the root of the problem, although not why it is suddenly causing an issue. We have some buttons where a ClientSideOnClick event is added manually. This seems to cause two postback methods to be added to the button (one manual and one automatic). If we do not add the manual event then everything works fine. Obviously we could turn off AutoEventWireup but then our page_load events etc would not be wired up properly (and there are a lot of pages in this app to fix if we do that). Can we disable the autoeventwireup just for the buttons?

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler to see if there any differences between good working and not good working pages?

Comment: The good and bad pages are the same page, just with a different some different options selected from dropdown boxes

Comment: Interesting. We have been told of similar issues on one of our SSL/TLS applications for some IE users, starting in the middle of last week. The issue arises on postback of a multipart/form-data. The browser hangs, the processing is done server side, but it seems that no response is sent back to the client...

Comment: @jbl, ours broke on 2nd October. We did install .net4.5 on the live server on the evening of the first. However we had installed 4.5 on the test server about 1 month ago and it has been working fine up until the 2nd October.....

Answer (score 2):

We have discovered that the cause of this issue is a combination of two things.

Firstly .net 4.5 was installed on the servers (it was installed on the test server some time ago, but the nature of this issue means that it seems it was not ever hit on the test server in that time).

Then we discovered (as posted above) that there were some instances where a buttons were given two JavaScript postback events.

These buttons have not been altered for at least 3 years and have been working fine (even if it is not best practice or even wanted behavior), however installing 4.5 framework on the server seems to have made these break in IE (yep, microsofts update only breaks the pages in microsofts own browser...).
. 
Now this means we can finally get the pages working again. However we still really do not know why installing .net framework 4.5 on the server broke code running in framework 4.0 which has been working fine for at least 3 years (possibly many more than that). Even more baffling is why it only broke in Internet Explorer.